# css fluid layout question

Tags: css

hi guys i've managed to create my css layout but whenever i try to set body_second and body_third to 100% it causes the screen to overflow. i don't want to invoke the scrollbar in any case.

i would like the css layout to resize to the window size without any need for overflow as seen on *http://biblia.com/* * try to resize the window when on the website in different browsers, i'm trying to achieve the same thing!

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>100% Height CSS Layout</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url(main_bg.png);
}
body {
    font-family: "lucida sans", verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
}
p {
    padding: 0 10px 1em;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    border-left: 0px solid #666;
    border-right: 0px solid #666;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
* html #container {
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.header_column {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
#header_second {
    margin-left: 50%;
    color:#FFF;
}
#header_third {
    margin-left: 80%;
    color:#FFF;
}
#body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.body_column {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#FFF;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#body_first {
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
    min-height: 60%;
}
#body_second {
    margin-left: 22%;
    width: 36%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    min-height: 85%;
    max-height: 90%;
}
#body_third {
    margin-left: 58%;
    width: 36%;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: #919191;
    min-height: 85%;
}
#footer {
    margin-top: 70%;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header_first" class="header_column"><img src="header_logo.png" width="35" height="16" border="0"></div>
    <div id="header_second" class="header_column">asdas</div>
    <div id="header_third" class="header_column">asdas</div>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="body_first" class="header_column">asdas</div>
    <div id="body_second" class="header_column">asdas</div>
    <div id="body_third" class="header_column">asdas</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">asdas</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your margins! 
If you set set #body_second's width to 100% of it's parent's width then add margin-left: 22% (essentially offsetting it 22% away from its parent's left side).. together.. it's going to overflow because that adds up to > 100%.